# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rcaller/RCaller in java-ee

Tags: java, r, maven, jakarta-ee, rcaller

I am trying to integrate regression R code into my j2ee project using R caller.
My datasource is from mysql database. So I used RMYSQL as package.
My code work fine under java project but when I moved it into backing bean class it throws an exception:  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rcaller/RCaller`

In maven dependency it exist only version 2.8 of Rcaller. And I'm in need to 2.5 version so I haved added it to build path manually.

The backing bean method is:

```
try {

       RCaller caller = new RCaller();
       RCode code = new RCode();  

       caller.setRscriptExecutable("Rscript.exe");
       code.clear();
       caller.setRCode(code);

       code.R_require("RMySQL");
       code.R_require("rpart");


       code.addRCode("mydb= dbConnect(MySQL(),user='root',password='root',dbname='db',host='localhost')"); 
       code.addRCode("rs= dbSendQuery(mydb,'select * from table')"); 
       code.addRCode("data = fetch(rs,n=-1)");  
       code.addRCode("data= data[data[['cred']]>0,]");  
       code.addRCode("data$navig <- ifelse(data$navig == 'Chrome',1,ifelse(data$navig == 'Firefox',2,ifelse(data$navig == 'Android',3,ifelse(data$navig == 'iPhone',4,9))))");  
       code.addRCode("data$rate =as.factor(data$rate)");  
       code.addRCode("ad.apprentissage= rpart(rate~vqs+ibt+tbt+bf+n+down+ping, data=data,minsplit = 7)");  
       code.addRCode("predArbreDecision=predict(ad.apprentissage,newdata=data,type='class') ");  
       code.addRCode("table(data$rate, predArbreDecision)");  


       File file = code.startPlot();
      // code.addRCode("ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method='lm') + ggtitle('y = f(x)')");
code.addRCode("plot(ad.apprentissage,main='Arbre de décision de la vidéo Streaming')");
code.addRCode("text(ad.apprentissage)");
       caller.runOnly();
       ImageIcon ii = code.getPlot(file);
       code.showPlot(file);

   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e.toString());
   }
```

And in order to display the graph in jsf page, I have called that function as following:

```
 #{video_R_IntegrationBean.Test3()}
```

Comment: Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `maven`, you have to follow the `maven` way.

If you have this jar of 2.5 version, please install it either in your local repository, or in a custom repository.
Please see [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html)

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar \
                                                                              -DgroupId=your.groupId \
                                                                              -DartifactId=your-artifactId \
                                                                              -Dversion=version \
                                                                              -Dpackaging=jar \
                                                                              -DlocalRepositoryPath=path-to-specific-local-repo
```

Once it is installed in your repository, you have to declare it in your `pom.xml` as dependency and of course dont forget to reference your local repository in `repositories` section.

Comment: I followed what you said, now the jar fil is successfully present in maven dependencies but same error occured :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rcaller/RCaller

Comment: i guess this is the correct version, right? i mean, if it wanst it wouldnt compile. does `mvn clean package` add this 2.5 jar inside the `WEB-INF\lib` folder of your generated war file?

Comment: No it's not present under WEB-INF\lib. But it is present in maven dependency.  I have added it as following:
 <dependency>
  <groupId>RCaller-2.5</groupId>
  <artifactId>RCaller-2.5</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/RCaller-2.5.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>

Comment: no please dont use system scope. you shouldnt add it as system scope. if you must use it that way, the point it to be inside the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your maven project and copy it there.